# How to get one element from a Pcollection in Apache Beam

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

considering a list of Pcollection:

**[{'id':'1','name':'Tom','country':'USA'},{'id':'2','name':'Oprah','country':'USA'}....]**

I want to count the occurrence of every country.
The result should be something like this:

**{'USA':2, 'Tunisia':3, 'France':1}**

Answer (score 1):

Check [beam.combiners.ToDict](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.2.0/apache_beam.transforms.combiners.html#apache_beam.transforms.combiners.ToDict), which produces a dict as a result;

Example:

```py
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions

p = beam.Pipeline(options=PipelineOptions()) 

(p  
| "create pcoll" >> beam.Create([{'id':'1','name':'Tom','country':'USA'},
                                                {'id':'2','name':'Oprah','country':'USA'},
                                                {'id':'2','name':'Oprah','country':'Italy'}])
| "map" >> beam.Map(lambda x: (x['country']))
| "count" >> beam.combiners.Count.PerElement()
| "toDict" >> beam.combiners.ToDict()
| "print" >> beam.Map(print)
) 

p.run()

# Result {'USA': 2, 'Italy': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to the word count example. You can find an implementation in python here - https://beam.apache.org/get-started/wordcount-example/